# iand with different kind parameters using new gfortran version

Tags: fortran, gfortran, type-kinds

I am currently working with old code, that calls the `iand` function with integers of different kinds as arguments. Here's a small example of what the code includes:

```
program test
    integer*1 i
    integer j, k 

    i = 1
    j = 8 

    k = iand(i, j)
    print *, k
end program test
```

gfortran versions 8 and earlier had as an extension the ability to call iand with integers of different kind (see, for instance, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gfortran/IAND.html#IAND)), whereas this option was removed in gfortran 9 (see [this site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gfortran/IAND.html#IAND)).
For instance, with gfortran 7.5.0:

```
gfortran-7 -o test test.f90 && ./test
       0
```

But when compiling with gfortran 9.2.0, I get:

```
gfortran -o test test.f90
...
Error: Arguments of ‘iand’ have different kind type parameters at (1)
```

Is there an option for the new version of `gfortran` to let me use this code as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. This extension was removed as the semantics weren't well specified, and fixing the code to be standard conforming is simple.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81509

In your case, something like

```
k = iand(int(i, kind(j)), j)
```

is hopefully what you're after.